# Loading image is shown too late for users with slow connection

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

The issues is with existing `ASP.NET MVC 4` project. The View itself is not that big but there are also several service calls and what happens is that people with slow internet connection reports that for some period of time when they request the page it stay unresponsive, so they don't know if the content is loading or something went wrong.

So in general, what I need is a way to show a loading image as the very first thing from this page (or at least fast enough) so even if it takes some time for the browser to download the full content, at least the user will know that something is going on.

However it seems that this is not as trivial as it sounds. I came up with two ideas, one was already proven to not work in all cases and the second is also something that many people doesn't recommend.

What I've tried was to use pure `JavaScript` in the `<head>` tag like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    document.write("<div style='margin-left: 50px; margin-top : 50px;'>LOADING...</div>"); 
</script>
</head>
```

Of course the styling is just to get the idea. This seemed like it was working until recently when on a minor build of `IE 11` the page broke which after some investigation was proven to be due to the usage of `document.write()` inside the `<head>` tag. Even though this seems to work on most browsers and versions the fact that it's a potential danger requires a change in the approach.

The second idea is pretty similar to this, again - writing directly in the `<head>` tag but this time instead of using `document.write()` just putting the html markup directly there. From what I've read this is also a recipe for disaster so I don't even want to try it, but those are the two ideas that I could came up with. Everything else just doesn't work for slow internet connections since the mainstream solutions relays on the fact that some part of the `DOM` is already loaded so you can use it to apply behaviour/style.

I hope I'm not the first one that got this problem so I would appreciate any suggestion on how to solve this issue. Since I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` there was an idea to use a dedicated controller with view which to get called first just for the sake of showing the loading image and then moving to the requested view. Even though this idea seems interesting I didn't have the time to think it over, it also sounds a pretty complicated, but anyways, all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When faced with the same issue, we did as you mentioned:  Load a super-light-weight page first with a tiny loading icon & "Loading..." text, then called back to the server to pull down the heavy content in chunks using ajax.

If you content is really heavy, it's also worth mentioning that you need make sure you have gzip compression turned on at your web server layer also.

Comment: Thnaks for the answer. I would like to ask you have you thought about implementing some sort of `BaseController` which to be the base class for all other controllers and instead making additional AJAX each time just call a view from the base controller? Those are some random thoughts but if you go through that and there's some reason not to do it you can save me some time. For some reason I don't like the additional AJAX call too much...

Answer (score 1):

Don't block the rendering of the DOM. Load the page and call your scripts right before the closing body tag and attach to an event like `DOMContentLoaded` or `window.load` (if you're using jQuery, that would be `$(document).ready`). In other words, you should allow the page to load completely, even if it's empty, before running any of your JavaScript.

Then, don't worry about writing the "Loading" div dynamically. Just include it in the rendered HTML and hide it initially. The first thing your JavaScript will do, before issuing any AJAX calls, is to show this "Loading" div.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the issue can be reproduced if you use GPRS connection in Chrome throttling, The page itself is not that big ~500kb but we are talking for very slow internet. Just letting the user wondering what's going on for 3-4 seconds is not acceptable, there has to be some sort of solution.

Comment: 500KB for an HTML document is *huge*. If that's the case, you need to slim down that thing or no solution will work. If you're talking about total page weight (images, JS, CSS, etc.), that doesn't matter. All that needs to be delivered is the HTML document itself before a loading message or similar can be displayed.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the HTML is pretty small, I'm talking about the page weight. So correct if I'm wrong - you suggest to add some pure JavaScript to the <head> and subscribing to the `DOMContentLoaded`, right? But from what I read some browsers wait till all content is loaded (not only the HTML markup) before they start rendering. Is there any way around that?

Comment: No. *Never* add JavaScript to the head. That's a big part of your problem. JavaScript blocks the rendering of the page until it finishes running. That's why your JavaScript should go before the closing body tag: so that the document has been rendered before the JavaScript is run.

Comment: And that is incorrect: no major browser on the market waits until everything has loaded before rendering the document. The HTML begins rendering as soon as it's delivered. Additional resources are loaded in parallel (4 or more at a time depending on OS and browser). Each piece is rendered as soon as it's available. Except JavaScript, which will block until loaded and run (which is why it should be the last thing on the page).

Comment: Hmm, guess I'll need to pay more attention to how I've build the page. Thanks for the insights. I'll wait to see if there will be some other answers but your was very useful!